# Create data frame of clicks in Shiny from ggplot base layer

Tags: r, shiny

I've written a function that takes a data frame of specific points and plots them using ggplot, creating a picture. I'd like to be able to take this picture and use it as a GUI for a Shiny app, where users can click anywhere on the picture, add some information from the click, and then append the click's coordinates and information to a data frame (that's originally empty). Ideally this data frame would be able to be downloaded for further analyses.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about including the functionality in the Shiny app? I'd share code, but the data frame is long and I don't have anything in the Shiny app yet to share. More specific information about the project upon request.

Comment: Yes it is possible. How about you share a some code that you have tried so we could help you out.

Comment: That's the thing: I don't really know how to start to go about this. I can share the functions I wrote, but in terms of Shiny I don't have anything in the app yet.

Comment: Have you tried going through [Shiny tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)?

Comment: I have, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: How about [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html) to get you started?

Comment: HUGE help, I can't believe I missed that! I've got that part working. Is there a way to pull files from the directory (and therefore a subdirectory) that contains the Shiny app script?

Comment: Maybe [shinyFiles](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll definitely check that out. Other issue I'm having: how can I get the ggplot to add a point after a user clicks? I've gotten the rest, but can't seem to get the clicked point to plot. I've tried geom_point() to no avail.

Comment: Code for what I've got so far can be found here: https://github.com/rossdrucker/nothing-but-net/blob/master/app.R

Comment: Could you create a minimal example and post it as a separate question so that it would be helpful for others that would run into similar query?

Comment: This is what I've created. I'm still stuck on it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190820/create-data-set-from-clicks-in-shiny-ggplot